# handling a fatal error in iphone app

Tags: iphone

how to handle error in an iphone app ? 
log and exit ? show an alert dialog and exit ?
for exemple, if an image is missing from the bundle..even though it should not ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are never supposed to exit the app programmatically. Advise the user there was a problem, offer to try it again, etc. But don't kill the app. This is explicit in the Apple HIG.

Let the user decide your app needs exiting. Don't do it for them.

Ideally, don't get yourself in this situation. : ) Easier said than done I know.

Comment: Doesn't offering to try again kindof assume the error isn't actually fatal?

Comment: Yes. The gist of the message is that NO errors in your app should be fatal.

Answer (score 2):

@Genericrich has it pretty spot on:

> Advise the user there was a problem, offer to try it again, etc. But don't kill the app. This is explicit in the Apple HIG.

The only advice I would add is to expect the unexpected. Just make sure your app is ready for those little blowups. This might be things like: default information to fill in the blanks, adequate alerts to let users know what's happening/retry, saving state before attempting failure prone destructive actions, and any other defensive programming habits you can think of.

As an added note if you are wanting to test network errors you may want to check out Craig Hockenberry's excellent post [Slow ride, make it easy](http://furbo.org/2009/03/24/slow-ride-make-it-easy/) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Alert box and exit should be fine. Short and sweet with just enough communication with the user to let them know why your software is about to not work.